# EditText, как в калькуляторах Android

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как настроить EditText так, чтобы при вводе текст размещался справа и автоматически сдвигался влево, когда заполнится сам EditText. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема решена. Дело было в курсоре. Я использовал StringBuilder для формирования строки и присваивал ее EditText. Из-за этого курсор постоянно был в начале. Решил проблему с помощью `editText.append("text")`, и курсор остается в конце. Спасибо за помощь, сам тупанул.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно в xml в editText дописать:

```
android:gravity="right"
```

**UPD1:**

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText" />
```

50dp хватит, чтобы показывать **только** 4 символа/цифры, все остальные(предыдущие) будут скрываться за EditText'ом.

Comment: Да, а как сделать, чтобы текст автоматически сдвигался влево, когда он не влезает в EditText?  
Например:  
В EditText влазит 5 символов. Я ввел 1234. Это выглядит так: | 1234|, я ввожу 56, и строка должна сдвинуться влево сама: |23456|, ввожу 789 - становится |56789|. Думаю, понятно объяснил.

Comment: Понятно, конечно. Смотрите обновление вопроса.

Comment: все равно, результат тот же: первые числа, которые влезли, остались на EditText, а новые скрываются справа от него и приходится скроллить вправо, чтобы их увидеть, я мне надо чтобы оно автоматически скролилось